# Azure Automation Account Runbook with Python Fails

Tags: python, azure, automation, azure-runbook

I'm trying to create an Automation Account, runbook, that I can then schedule to run daily. This works in Python for the developer that created it, they are able to run it add-hoc. When I created this as a runbook and tested in the test pane I had an error. I'm lost now, where do I need to install the Azure-Core Modules within the Automation Account? The account setting has 'Run as accounts' enabled, I have also assigned 'Identities'.[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YH1PW.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @AndrewD you can refer to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/python-3-packages) on how to manage python packages in Azure Automation account